# Facing Terraform KeyVault Certificates creation issue

Tags: terraform, azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure

hello everyone I am facing issue I have a script in which I am creating resource group and key vault and I copied the credentials from central KV into new one when I create RG and Key vault alone and then add Credentials copy portion into the script everything gets created but when I combine the code where 1 RG and 1 KV along with the credentials copy happens it says the Error Key vault in RG is does not exist. I am asking that is there any sequence in terraform do I need to follow ?
**Resource.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "main" {
  name     = "${var.prefix}-resourceGB"
  location = var.location
}

# --- Get reference to logged on Azure subscription ---
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}


resource "azurerm_key_vault" "New" {
  name                        = "KV1"
  location                    = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  enabled_for_disk_encryption = true
  tenant_id                   = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  soft_delete_enabled         = true
  purge_protection_enabled    = false


  sku_name = "standard"


  access_policy {
    tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
    object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

    certificate_permissions = [
      "create",
      "delete",
      "deleteissuers",
      "get",
      "getissuers",
      "import",
      "purge",
      "list",
      "listissuers",
      "managecontacts",
      "manageissuers",
      "setissuers",
      "update",
    ]

    key_permissions = [
      "backup",
      "create",
      "decrypt",
      "delete",
      "encrypt",
      "get",
      "import",
      "list",
      "purge",
      "recover",
      "restore",
      "sign",
      "unwrapKey",
      "update",
      "verify",
      "wrapKey",
    ]

    secret_permissions = [
      "backup",
      "delete",
      "get",
      "list",
      "purge",
      "recover",
      "restore",
      "set",
    ]


  }
}
data "azurerm_key_vault" "existing" {
  name                = "Old-KV"
  resource_group_name = "Old-RG"

}

data "azurerm_key_vault" "New" {
  name                = "KV1"
  resource_group_name = "${var.prefix}-resourceGB"
}

module "Cert1" {
  source = "../module/copy_cert"
  source_key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.existing.id
  source_key_vault_cert_name = "Cert1"
  destination_key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.New.id
  destination_key_vault_cert_name = "Cert1"

}
module "Cert2" {
  source = "../module/copy_cert"
  source_key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.existing.id
  source_key_vault_cert_name = "Cert2"
  destination_key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.New.id
  destination_key_vault_cert_name = "Cert2"

}
```

**Copy Cert main.tf**

```
data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "source_KV_cert" {
  name         = var.source_key_vault_cert_name
  key_vault_id = var.source_key_vault_id
}


data "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "source_cert" {
  name         = var.source_key_vault_cert_name
  key_vault_id = var.source_key_vault_id
}


resource "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "dest_cert" {
  name         = var.destination_key_vault_cert_name
  key_vault_id = var.destination_key_vault_id


certificate {
    contents = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.source_KV_cert.value
  }


  certificate_policy {
    issuer_parameters {
      name = "self"
    }


    key_properties {
      exportable = true
      key_size   = 2048
      key_type   = "RSA"
      reuse_key  = true
    }


    secret_properties {
      content_type = "application/x-pkcs12"
    }


  }


}
```

**Copy Cert Variable.tf**

```
variable "source_key_vault_id" {
  type    = string
}
variable "source_key_vault_cert_name" {
  type    = string
}

variable "destination_key_vault_id" {
  type    = string
}

variable "destination_key_vault_cert_name" {
  type    = string
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code where 1 RG and 1 KV along with the credentials copy happens? make sure you have all the .tf files in the same directory.

Comment: kindly see my updated answer @NancyXiong here is my version output.
PS D:\environments> terraform version

Your version of Terraform is out of date! The latest version
is 0.13.4. You can update by downloading from https://www.terraform.io/downloads.html
Terraform v0.13.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v2.18.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random v2.3.0

Comment: Could you show what's the specific error message?

Comment: Error: KeyVault "KV1" (Resource Group "my-resourceGB") does not exist

  on resources.tf line 82, in data "azurerm_key_vault" "KV1":
  82: data "azurerm_key_vault" "KV1" {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are creating a new key vault with `resource "azurerm_key_vault"`, you can't use the data source to query for a new resource that is creating at that time in your modules `module "Cert1"` and `module "Cert2"` in the same `.tf` file. The [data "azurerm_key_vault"](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/key_vault.html) is used to access information about an existing Key Vault.

So change the related code in the file `Resource.tf` like this:

```
# data "azurerm_key_vault" "New" {
#   name                = "KV1"
#   resource_group_name = "${var.prefix}-resourceGB"
# }

module "Cert1" {
  source = "../module/copy_cert"
  source_key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.existing.id
  source_key_vault_cert_name = "Cert1"
  destination_key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.New.id     # changed
  destination_key_vault_cert_name = "Cert1"

}
module "Cert2" {
  source = "../module/copy_cert"
  source_key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.existing.id
  source_key_vault_cert_name = "Cert2"
  destination_key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.New.id      # changed
  destination_key_vault_cert_name = "Cert2"

}
```